# Extra whitespace when rendering a text_area in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting an extra white space inside the text area when rendering this HAML code.

```
= f.text_area :message, placeholder: "Reply"
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.3 and haml-rails 0.3.4 and haml 3.1.4

I have no idea why this is happening.

This is the code rendered with the extra whitespace

```
<textarea class="textarea" cols="50" id="idea_idea" name="idea[idea]" rows="2">&#x000A;</textarea>
```

Comment: Are you sure about your version of haml-rails? I have rails 3.2.3 and haml-rails 0.3.4 (latest, if not mistaken). Anyway, I don't have any extra whitespaces, can you post your generated html for this helper?

Comment: Updated: haml-rails version is 0.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a solution to this problem.

I upgraded to the "3.1.5" beta version of HAML and works fine now.

```
gem 'haml', :git => "git://github.com/haml/haml.git", :branch => "315"
```

Comment: Same here with haml 3.1.4.
3.1.6 seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are running should have similar issues fixed, see the ActionPack Changelog linked below, it appears to contain multiple entries related to the issue.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md